# Something Like A Catch-All Action In a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes, action

I have a controller named ProfileController, and what I'm trying to do is make it so I can redirect or search for users based on their usernames. Something like www.site.com/Profile/MyUsername and then it bring up a view with that particular user model. Only way I can come seem to do this is to pass an int Id as a parameter but even then it comes out as www.site.com/Profile/Index/1 when I'd really like to get rid of the Index part altogether and replace the 1 with the actual username... Has anyone done this before?

Comment: You can use custom routes to accomplish this kind of behaviour. Also read here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx .

Comment: Why can't you directly pass the username itself instead of the id?

Comment: Profile is your controller and Index is your action. Why not name the action ShowUser or something more meaningful than Index - and as @styxxy suggested, pass the user name (assuming it's unique) so you end up with site.com/Profile/ShowUser/MyUserName

Comment: Well the reason I went with Index is because it doesn't show up when you just go directly to .com/Profile I don't really want to show the action name would rather just show the username but might just have to go this route instead.